# Write the equation in the form a + ib

Tags: complex-analysis, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve this exercise!

$i + i^2 + i^3 + \ldots + i^n \quad    (n > 4)$

I did the calculation,

i^1 = i

i^2 = − 1

i^3 = i^2 * i = -i

i^4 = i^2 * i^2 = 1

i^5 = i, so basically, every n + 4, the answer is i

But what is next? How can I write it in the form a + ib?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: You already gave the answer, how to write $i^k$ as $a+bi$, right? Now sum up, or use the geometric series.

Comment: You asked this yesterday.  What was unclear about the answers you received then?  Ask for more clarification on the already existing post rather than opening a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence. You can convert the number you get to the desired form.
Another method is to notice some pattern in this sum. Try calculating the sum of the first few terms and see if you catch it.